# Duration in d3 animation

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I'm trying to animate width of a rectangle in d3 like this:

```
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 20)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .style('fill',barColor)
    .transition()
    .attr("width", 200)
    .duration(1000)
    .delay(1000);
```

I'm trying to increase the width to 200 px over a period of 1 sec, but the animation is not happening.
Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set an initial value for the width in order for D3 to be able to interpolate and transition:

```
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 20)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("width", 0)
  .style('fill',barColor)
.transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("width", 200);
```